# Request cached when using HTTP/2

Tags: angularjs, ssl, http2

I have a strange behaviour I can't explain with http/2:

During an oauth authentication process, I'm trying to login on A.domain, using B.domain provider. When both servers have HTTP/2 enabled, and using the same ssl cert (a wildcard), on the same IP (so with TLS SNI) the request to B.domain (I have the url B.domain in the address bar, and the headers) is sent to A.domain! 
I could reproduce this with firefox and chrome, but not safari.
We're using angular 1.6, but I doubt it's a JS issue. 
If the domain is different, the problem goes away.

Could it be a bug in the http/2 implementation in chrome and firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under HTTP/2 connections can be reused under a process known as coalescing.

This is to allow full HTTP/2 benefits even when sharding has been used to improve performance for HTTP/1.1 connection - which is no longer necessary under HTTP/2 and in fact is bad for performance (since the setting up of additional connections takes resources on both client and server).

This blog post gives much more detail about HTTP/2 connection coalescing and how the different browsers coalesce differently: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/18/http2-connection-coalescing/

However I am confused when you say it "is sent to A.domain". The *connection* should be reused but the web server should then process it under the appropriate domain. If this is not happening then it sounds like a bug in the HTTP/2 implementation on the web server you are using.

Comment: Yes, I can see the default page from A.domain, even if all headers and the navigation bar indicates B.domain. That's the scary part.

Comment: In inspector, I can see a header "Host: B.domain", yet, the response headers are clearly from A.domain. There's a button "Edit and resend" on firefox, if I use it, and send the same request again, the page is served by B.domain. The problem goes away if I disable http/2 in firefox.

Comment: I've taken a look at the article you mentioned, and it's very likely the issue I have. Thanks for sharing your knowledge on this, I'm validating your answer :)

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. The connection should be reused but the server should still handle this and return the appropriate content. Which server are you using as it sounds like a bug in that which is leaking information across domains.

Comment: We're using the default openshift routers, so it's HAProxy

Comment: With Edge termination on B.domain, and passthrough on a.domain

Comment: HAProxy doesn't support HTTP/2 AFAIK so you are using HAProxy as a TCP proxy and then passing requests for A and B domain on to another web server (which one?) which does the HTTP/2 termination? And are they on the same IP address too? Limited in what can add to comments so would be good for you to edit your question and describe your full infrastructure so can understand why this might be happening.